# Again on typename and template keywords

Tags: c++, templates, typename, dependent-name

I have carefully read many answers concerning this topic, but nevertheless I cannot figure out EXACTLY when these two keywords ARE or AREN'T needed in the scope of a non-template function which is member of a nested template class.

My reference compilers are GNU g++ 4.9.2  and clang 3.5.0.

They behave hardly different on the following code where I put embedded
comments trying to explain what happens.

```
#include <iostream>

// a simple template class with a public member template struct
template <class Z>
class Pa
{
// anything
public:
    template <class U>
    struct Pe  // a nested template
    {
        // anything
        void f(const char *); // a non-template member function
    };

    template <class U> friend struct Pe;
};

// definition of the function f
template <class AAA>
template <class BBB>
void Pa<AAA> :: Pe<BBB> :: f(const char* c)
{
    Pa<AAA> p; // NO typename for both clang and GNU...

    // the following line is ACCEPTED by both clang and GNU
    // without both template and typename keywords
    // However removing comments from typename only
    // makes clang still accepting the code while GNU doesn't
    // accept it anymore. The same happens if the comments   of template
    // ONLY are removed.
    //  
    // Finally both compilers accept the line when both typename AND
    // template are present...
    /*typename*/ Pa<AAA>::/*template*/ Pe<BBB> q;

    // in the following clang ACCEPTS typename, GNU doesn't:
    /*typename*/ Pa<AAA>::Pe<int> qq;

    // the following are accepted by both compilers
    // no matter whether both typename AND template
    // keywords are present OR commented out:
    typename Pa<int>::template Pe<double> qqq;
    typename Pa<double>::template Pe<BBB>  qqqq;
    std::cout << c << std::endl; // just to do something...
}

int main()
{
    Pa<char>::Pe<int> pp;
    pp.f("bye");
}
```

So, in the scope of `f` is `Pa<double>::Pe<BBB>` a dependent name or not?

And what about `Pa<AAA>::Pe<int>` ?

And, after all, why this different behaviour of the two quoted compilers?

Can anyone clarify solving the puzzle?

Comment: "They behave hardly different"... as I understand your question, you wonder why the do behave different, in this case "hardly" is the wrong word. Actually what you describe is that they hardly behave the same ;)

Comment: GCC can't seem to cope with the name anymore as soon as you sprinkle `typename` or `template` and "forgets" about `P<AAA>` being the surrouding template. I think GCC has a bug here and recommend making a PR. There is no need for `typename` or `template` here.

Comment: The rules for *allowing* `typename` where it is strictly not needed have been relaxed recently. Probably after the release of gcc 4.9. Could explain example 3.

Comment: `Pa<double>::Pe<BBB>` is a dependent name in the sense that its type is dependent on `BBB`. But that doesn't mean you are required to insert `typename`. This is true also for `Pa<AAA>::Pe<int>` and `Pa<AAA>`. In all these cases, the compiler can figure out itself that `Pe` is a template and `Pe<int>` / `Pe<BBB>` is a type. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17579889/34509

Answer (score 3):

The important rule in [temp.res] is:

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1)
>   and its *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming
>   a *typename-specifier*. If the *qualified-id* in a *typename-specifier* does not denote a type, the program is ill-formed.

The question revoles around two *qualified-id*s:

```
Pa<double>::Pe<BBB>
Pa<AAA>::Pe<int>
```

First, what is a dependent type? According to [temp.dep.type]:

> A type is dependent if it is
>   — a template parameter,
>   — a member of an unknown specialization,
>   — a nested class or enumeration that is a dependent member of the current instantiation,
>   — a cv-qualified type where the cv-unqualified type is dependent,
>   — a compound type constructed from any dependent type,
>   — an array type whose element type is dependent or whose bound (if any) is value-dependent,
>   — a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template
>   arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent, or
>   — denoted by `decltype`(*expression*), where *expression* is type-dependent (14.6.2.2).

`Pa<double>` (the *nested-name-specifier* of the first example) is not a dependent type, as it fits none of the bullet points. Since we don't meet that criteria, we don't need to prefix the `typename` keyword.

`Pa<AAA>`, however, *is* a dependent type since it is a *simple-template-id* in which one of the template arguments is a dependent type (`AAA` is trivially a dependent type since it is a template parameter).

What, then, is "a member of the current instantiation"?

> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is
>   — [...]
>   — in the definition of a primary class template or a member of a primary class template, the name of the class template followed by the template argument list of the primary template (as described below) enclosed in <> (or an equivalent template alias specialization)"
>   — in the definition of a nested class of a class template, the name of the nested class referenced as a
>   member of the current instantiation, or

The current instantiation, in this case, is `Pa<AAA>` (or, also, `Pa`). And:

> A name is a member of the current instantiation if it is [...] A *qualified-id* in which the *nested-name-specifier* refers to the current instantiation and that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof.

So `Pe` is a member of the current instantiation. Thus, while the *nested-name-specifier* of `Pa<AAA>::Pe<int>` is a dependent type, it is a type that is a member of the current instantiation, so you do not need the keyword `typename`. Note that `Pa<AAA>::Pe<int>` *is* a dependent type itself (it's a nested class that is a dependent member of the current instantiation), but that in itself does mean that the `typename` keyword is required.

The fact that gcc doesn't accept typename here:

```
/*typename*/ Pa<AAA>::Pe<int> qq;
```

because it wants

```
typename Pa<AAA>::template Pe<int> qq;
```

is a bug.